# Remove border around image in Pygame

Tags: python, performance, border, pygame

I have got some surfaces in Pygame with a transparent background. They're all the same size. But there's a different sized circle drawn on each of them, so the circle doesn't exactly fit the image.
Here are some example images (I took a screenshot in Photoshop so you can clearly see the transparency and the size of the images):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now I want to remove the transparent border around the image so the circle exactly fits into the image. I don't want the surface to be circle shaped, I don't think that's possible, but I want that the surface doesn't have blank columns on the left and right and that it doesn't have any blank rows on the top and the bottom. The wanted results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The circle on the surfaces changes size every frame so I have to recalculate the new surfaces every frame.

I already Googled it, but I haven't found anything for Pygame surfaces yet. I also tried making my own function but it looks ugly and much worse: the framerate drops from 50 (if I don't call the function) to 30 fps (if I do call the function). I tested it a little bit and I found out that smaller circles take longer to process than bigger circles. How can I do this, but faster. If you want I can show the function I made.

Comment: Hello there!  Your question is quite difficult to understand.  Consider adding some images and structuring the flow of your question to help.

Comment: I edited it, now it should be more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The surface object has a method called `get_bounding_rect` which is where we will start.  The function returns the smallest rect possible which contains all of the non-transparent pixels on the surface.

```
pixel_rect = image.get_bounding_rect()
```

With the size of this rect, we can create a new surface:

```
trimmed_surface = pygame.Surface(pixel_rect.size)
```

Now blit the portion of `image` contained within `pixel_rect` onto `trimmed_surface`:

```
trimmed_surface.blit(image, (0,0), pixel_rect)
```

At this point, `trimmed_surface` should be a surface the same size as `pixel_rect`, with the unwanted transparent rows and columns "trimmed" off of the original surface.

Documentation for Surface.get_bounding_rect: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.get_bounding_rect